# DivSmoothScroll not scrolling at all

Tags: jquery, html, scroll

Okay, here's my problem:
I had [DivSmoothScroll](http://www.smoothdivscroll.com/) running just fine, then I moved the div further down in the source and it suddenly stopped working.

I would also accept better alternatives to implement that behavior.

The URL:
http://cassel-classic-cars.de/n/

Answer (score 0):

I checked the site using chrome and found this error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'printId' of undefined`. It seems to be a problem with the lytebox.js. I suggest to get rid of this error first.

Comment: It's not related, I added the lytebox after the scrolling stopped working. But I'll remove the lytebox now.